# Java applet send information to a php page

Tags: java, php, mysql, applet

I was wondering if it was possible to send information from a java applet to a PHP page (and in the long run, a mysql database) on the click of a button (within the java applet).
Of course, if it's easier to just incorporate the jar file instead of an applet, that's also a possibility, but I just don't know how to do that...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that. You'll need to grant the Applet permissions to access the network though. [Here's an example](http://www.innovation.ch/java/HTTPClient/HTTPClientExample.html).

Comment: By default applets have permission to connect to (and receive connections from) the host they were downloaded from (a Same Origin Policy).

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline: yes, true. But I'm not sure if that's the case here.

Comment: How do I access the data sent from the applet from the php?